# WinForm for creating ADO.NET Entities that have relationships with other entities

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I am very new to the ADO Entity Framework, and I'm looking for the best practice.

Here is the scenario:  I have a database with a `Person` table and an `Address` table.  `Person` has a foreign key referencing the primary key of `Address`, an auto-incrementing int.  First, I've created an ADO Entity model with VS 2010, and sure enough the relationship is understood by the IDE.

Now I want to create a Windows Form that allows the user to fill in a `Person`'s basic info and `Address`.  Normally, I can just drag the `Person` entity onto a blank Windows Form, and VS2010 will automatically create the necessary fields along with the binding.  But what extra work do I need to do in order to ensure the following happens when this form is filled out by the user:

1. The `Address` portion of the form is saved in the `Address` table
2. The `Person` information is saved in the `Person` table, along with the primary key of the `Address` created in 1.
3. The user never touches/sees any primary keys.

I think my confusion is coming from the fact that I am expecting the IDE to do more coding than it's supposed to; If I had to quickly hack this, I'd probably add a click event to the "save" button that first calls SaveChanges() on the `Address` followed by the `Person`.  Is that the best practice, or is there a more accepted way of doing this?

Comment: I apologize in advance knowing that this scenario comes up a lot, but I couldn't quite find the answer by searching.

Comment: Are you modeling: Multiple persons live on 1 address?

Comment: It could happen.  I like having an address table where ALL addresses are stored, as there will be other entities that may refer to it.  Furthermore, I'd like to know what the best practice is from a more general standpoint.

Comment: You could just as easily be modeling: 1 Person has multiple addresses. And of course the NxN model of multiple persons living on shared addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do a lot extra. But you should call SaveChanges on the DataContext common to Address and Person (to correctly handle the different insert/delete scenarios).

You should simply delete all controls (columns) relating to the Keys.

Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I'm not having a specific problem; just getting adjusted to C#/ADO/.NET.

I also knew I could delete the controls relating to keys, but I was more unsure about how related entities are saved on the same form.  I think I'll need to read up on DataContext, as it seems like there is more to this than I thought.

Comment: Yes, read up. There are multiple ways to create new objects too. But it is relatively easy. Don't fiddle with the keys, instead add entities to collections or set them in properties.